# How do I make a License and copyright notice

Tags: license, npm

Use these packages :

[image]

When I want a license and copyright notice, do I do it for these packages only, or all the packages belonging to these packages?

Comment: Images are not readable by screen readers. Please quote text as text and not as image

Answer (score 3):

When you distribute software you need to include the license and notice information (as required by the respective licenses of the libraries) for all the direct and all transitive dependencies.

There are wonderful open-source tools to help you with that task, for example [FOSSology](https://www.fossology.org/) or other tools published by the [Open Chain Project](https://github.com/Open-Source-Compliance).

Comment: Even all packages that belong to these packages؟؟

Comment: Yes, all of them, even if there are 100 levels of sub-sub-sub-dependencies. Proper software like the one I linked (from the Linux Foundation) will help you with the task.